# Execute SQL Query on Databricks SQL Warehouse using Rest API

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Is there a way to execute a SQL query on Databricks SQL Warehouse using Rest API?

I can see in the documentation that there are APIs to create a query, but don't see any API to run a query.

Answer (score 1):

As of 6/7/2023 this is now possible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/sql-execution-tutorial

Full API reference here:
https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/statementexecution/executestatement

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use REST Api?  Spark has always had a JDBC endpoint.  Just send a valid Spark SQL query against the built Hive Tables.  See documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-distributed-sql-engine.html).

Just query the interactive spark cluster that you leave up.  I have not used the new SQL Data Warehouse version of Databricks.  But I am sure there is something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Right now (November 2022nd) there is no public REST API to perform query on the SQL Warehouse, but it's in the roadmap.

But you can write a small wrapper either around [JDBC/ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi), or even using connectors for [Python](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-python)/[Go](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-go)/[Node.js](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-nodejs) to implement REST API.